# Как убрать Woof (HUSKY) с текстовых страниц и из страницы корзины

Tags: woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, популярно как убрать виджет плагина Woof с текстовых страниц и оставить только в категориях, где ему и место? В настройках не нашла от слова совсем.